# Netbeans 6.9.1 installation error : "No compatible JDK was found."

Tags: netbeans-6.9, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Netbeans 6.9.1 in my Ubuntu 9.04.

But when i run the script 
 `./netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh`, the installer GUI displays the error "No compatible JDK was found.",
and in the next window it asks for the installed JDK path.
What can I do to get it to install?

Comment: i have installed JDK 6 update 27 and then i'm trying to install Netbeans 6.9.1 and also display "No Compatible JDK was found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have installed a Java development kit that is compatible with the Netbeans version you're trying to install in your system. If not, you have to download the JDK and install it. Then try to run the installation again. download the Java JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-jsp-136632.html). You can check whether you have installed an JDK by issuing the command `javac` at the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site. I have encountered same problem as well. I research on how to get JDK compatibility and I am lead here..

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html

Should there be any other things, feel free to contribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dude the version of 6.9.1 and 6.0.1 are supported by JDK versions 1.5 other things after 6.9.1 are  edited when oracle bought sun and they revoke their support for these older versions i hope. so better go for 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is only due to javahome path missing.

If you don't have the JDK, then you can install it from java.

if you have the JDK installation directory then you can use below command line option while installing you net beans. Use the command line below:

For Windows OS - Open your command prompt

```
netbeans-6.9.1-windows.exe --javahome "C:\\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6"
```

For Linux OS - Open your Terminal

```
netbeans-6.9.1-windows.sh --javahome /usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_04
```

The should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fastest and easiest one for me.

1. go to enviroment variable
2. click on new
3. for variable name type in

   ```
   JAVA_HOME
   ```
4. for path type in

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this problem, which I have encountered. Those are mentioned below:

1. JDK is not installed in your machine
2. The path of JDK is not set in Environmental variables
3. The version of JDK and NetBeans is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $JAVA_HOME setup to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` installing NetBeans 8.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 wont work.

The fix is simple, just run.

`./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`