# Netbeans 6.9.1 not working on windows 8

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I want to make `Java Desktop Application` but Netbeans 6.9.1 is not working on windows 8.1 (it crashes on double click to run). I have installed `JDK8` along with `Jre7` (both 32 and 64 bit). How to make it run, Netbeans 8 is working properly.

Comment: How does it crashes? Did you try to google it?

Comment: *I have installed JDK8 along with Jre7 (both 32 and 64 bit)* ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899225/netbeans-6-9-1-installation-error-no-compatible-jdk-was-found

Comment: Any objections to use the latest version of Netbeans?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg it crashes,when i double click it to run.

Comment: @user3301492 netbeans 6.9.1 is only that supports java desktop application project

Comment: I see. By the way there is a modern tool which is very nice - JavaFX Scene Builder. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Netbeans 6.9.1 is not working on windows 8.1

> You must have JDK 6.0 on your system to install and run NetBeans IDE 6.9.1.

Source [NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 Release Notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/relnotes.html).

To make Netbeans run on JDK 6, if you have more than one JDK do this:

> You can change the JDK for Netbeans by modifying the config file:
>
> Open netbeans.conf file available under etc folder inside the NetBeans
>   installation. Modify the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable to point to new JDK
>   path, and then Restart your Netbeans.

**Sample**

```
# Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir>:
#netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
```

Comment: I just installed jdk6u38 64bit and set variables but still not working

Answer (score 0):

mainly the problem is that your netbeans and jdk are not compatible. you should download lastest jdk 8 and netbeans which you can from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html).

**DONT FORGET TO SET PATH.**

Comment: I want to use netbeans 6.9.1 for a specific reason and jdk 8 isn't compatible this version of netbeans.

Comment: i just installed jdk6u38 64bit and set variables but still not working

Comment: i tried SET PATH=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38 but netbeans still crashes

Comment: right click on netbeans select prop>run in compatibility with window 7 or xp. try that @JerryGoyal

Comment: that didn't help, i'll give a try on jdk5

Comment: finally it worked with Jdk6.
In the system variables I made a new variable, called it JAVA_HOME, and I set the value to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38 After that, I edited "Path", which is also in the system variables and I added : ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: select my answer :P still nice work man enjoy developing.@JerryGoyal

Answer (score 0):

**I got a Solution** 
You must have JDK 6.0 on your system.
Then  ***SET PATH*** at time of installation to ***JDK 6.0*** .