# NetBeans: No compatible JDk was found

Tags: java

i downloaded and installed the jdk-8u20 at first and tried to install NetBeans IDE 8.0.1. but it says "No compatible JDK was found". Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 6.9.1 installation error : "No compatible JDK was found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899225/netbeans-6-9-1-installation-error-no-compatible-jdk-was-found)

Comment: maybe helpful http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/I-went-install-NETBEANS-now-but-says-quot-No-compatible-JDK-was-found-quot-what-to-do-td5711275.html

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have JDK(Java dev. Kit) and not just JRE(Java runtime Edition). Otherwise try manually pointing it to your jdk file, or they have a version that comes with jdk which might work [that can be found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html)